# Where can I find a complete list of Dutch Control Verbs and Raising Verbs?

Tags: dutch, complement, raising, control

For my study on Dutch 'Infinitivus pro Participio' (IPP), I am looking for a complete list of dutch raising and control verbs.

Comment: Good luck. Be sure to look carefully at any you find. There are a lot more definitions of 'control' (aka 'equi') and 'raising' than you might imagine. A lot depends on the syntactic tests applied: have you got a list of them?